# Combining multiple xml-files into 1 file (different folders)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am a bit stuck on the following. I have around 200-xml files and I would like to combine all files into 1 file. All the 200 files are in different folders (200 folders ;)). The structure looks like:

\documents\work\folder1.xml1

\documents\work\folder2.xml2

...

\documents\work\folder200.xml200

I have the xsl to combine all the files into 1 file but the .xml files needs to be in the same folder and thats a lot of work. My question is, how can I make the xsl work so it reads all the folders and combines all the xml files or how can I grab all the xml files and put them in the same folder.

The xsl I am using is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="rootcopy"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="rootcopy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="folderURI" select="resolve-uri('.',base-uri())"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="collection(concat($folderURI, '?select=*.xml;recurse=yes'))/*/node()">
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Kind regards,

ASB

Comment: So which XSLT 2 processor do you use? If that is Saxon 9, have you tried to pull in all files from `collection('file:///documents/work?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')`?

Comment: I fixed it with a small empty xml file just above the folders with only the root mentioned. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: If you use `collection` then you don't need any primary input file, you can just start with a named template. And the URI for the `collection` function can be passed in as a parameter.